# why are Particle emission so different than other programs

Tags: particles

I have have used particle systems in Maya and Houdini, in which there is an **emitter rate** (how many particles are emitted per a second) and a particle **lifespan** (how long until the particles die).

In Blender when you create an emitter you have your lifetime (**lifespan**) but the particle emitter is only exposed indirectly through *Emission* and *Start* and *End* frame.

If you change the length of your scene, you have to change reconfigure you particle settings.

In Blender your are limited by constantly having to readjust your start and end frame alongside the emission.

Is there a benefit to this restriction and is there a workaround in order to have the same emission independantly of emision time?

<sup>[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q_v3KfwdMaA) showcases the feature I would prefer.</sup>

Comment: Hi, I downvoted your question, because it is very hard to find out what you are asking about. I'd advise you to restructure your question, remove everything that is not essential to the question and restructure your sentences into paragraphs. Is your question: **How do I control the particle emission rate?** Then rephrase it as such, so that it doesn't resemble a rant.

Comment: I have edited your post and retracted my vote. Please review it and check if it still is what you wanted to convey. Please note, that feature request and open discussion are not accepted as question on this site. Find out more in the [tour](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: thank you for the edit your version is much better than my original